# Merging tags [template] and [templates]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Both tags [template](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/template) and [templates](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/templates) refer to the same subject and thus should be merged.

Qs tagged [template](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/template)
Qs tagged [templates](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/templates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been done and a synonym created for `template` > `templates`